# Special character showing before £ sign in CSV file made with PHP

Tags: php, csv, encoding

I'm trying to generate a csv file with PHP and one column contains a cash value. I'd like to add a '£' sign before the number - but everything I have tried, and everything I've found on Stackoverflow doesn't seem to help and the Excel output always has a strange character infront of the £ symbol (see below).

[image]

I have pasted some of my code here (I've taken out other rows which were not relevant). Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputs($output, $bom = (chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)));

fputcsv( $output, array('Cash collected'));

$i = 0;
foreach ($quizzes as $key => $value) {
    $i++;

    $poundsign = html_entity_decode('&#163;', ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'utf-8');
    $modified_values = array(
        $poundsign . $value->quiz_cash,
    );

    );
    fputcsv( $output, $modified_values );

}

fclose($output);

$dest_output = 'output.csv';
$output_size = filesize($dest_output);

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
if(isset($_GET['brwry']) || $_GET['brwry'] == NULL):
    $filename = '' . $brewerytitle;
else:
    $filename = 'All breweries';
endif;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . " " . $_GET['start'] . " - " . $_GET['end'] . ".csv\";" );
header("Content-Length: " . $output_size);
readfile($dest_output);

exit;
```

Thanks,
Lloyd

Comment: What's wrong with `$poundsign = £;` instead of all the HTML decoding stuff?

Comment: P.S. If you view the CSV file in something like notepad++ rather than excel, do you see the same issue?

Comment: Hi @ADyson - Using a plain £ sign produces the same problem. I just opened in Notepad, and the special character also shows still.

Comment: As an experiment, if you get PHP to write the CSV to a file rather than outputting via the browser, does the output file in that scenario exhibit the same issue? Just trying to rule out one or two things.

Comment: @ADyson The code currently outputs to a file. I just removed the 'content-type' and 'content-disposition' headers so it outputs into the browser, and the £ signs display correctly

Comment: `The code currently outputs to a file`...no, it writes to the PHP output and then gets downloaded via the browser. I mean writing it _directly_ to a file on the webserver. As in , changing `fopen('php://output', 'w');` so it points to a file on disk.

Comment: Although, as well as that, you seem to be reading from a file called output.csv into the output too.